# Swift how to get cell from prepare for segue in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

Im using autolayout and for the life of me cannot set the proceeding view controller image view with the previous view controller collection view cell's image. Im using

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "openDetailView", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openDetailView" {
        let cell = sender as? ImageCollectionViewCell
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailedImageViewController
        detailVC.imageToPresent = cell?.imageView.image

    }
}
```

This is the class that I have already set up to receive the image

```
class DetailedImageViewController : UIViewController{

var imageToPresent: UIImage!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = imageToPresent
}
```

}

The segue performs as expected but the image DOES NOT show in detailedImageViewController. Thanks in advance.

Comment: changing the didSelectItemAt body did the trick:    performSegue(withIdentifier: "openDetailView", sender: collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath))

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to set the imageToPresent into a UIImageview in order to show the image.</strike>

```
class DetailedImageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imageToPresent : UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = imageToPresent 
    }
 ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that i do have this set up

Comment: You can try to load the code in viewWillAppear  instead of using viewDidLoad.

viewDidLoad only is called the first time when the viewController's view is loaded

Answer (score 0):

It's not a best practice to avoid optional unwrapping in this case. Try to use this code and check the errors if they happen.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openDetailView" {
        guard let cell = sender as? ImageCollectionViewCell else {
            assertionFailure("Failed to unwrap sender. Try to set a breakpoint here and check what sender is") 
            return 
        }
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailedImageViewController
        guard let cellImage = cell.imageView.image else {
            assertionFailure("The cell has no image in image view") 
            return 
        }
        detailVC.imageToPresent = cellImage
    }
}
```